# Onclick Confirm Not working

Tags: javascript

Hello I have this line of code.

```
onClick="confirm('Are you sure you want to update the database
   to the latest version?')"><li class="navb">Update Version
```

But the problem is even if the user clicks cancel or no. It will still perform the function. Would appreciate any help on what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: How you are handling the Ok or cancel button click...show your JS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use `return confirm(...)` instead of just `confirm(...)` for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm function actually returns a boolean. It's true if the user clicks ok, and false if cancel is clicked.
So you need to save the return value of confirm function in a variable, and then check that variable to perform desired operations.